# Loading an image file in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, comexception

I have a WinRT project, and am getting an error when trying to preview an image.  I have set capabilities to allow access to the Pictures library, and am using the following code:

```
 var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(path);
 var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
 var img = new BitmapImage();
 img.SetSource(fileStream);
```

This error occurs on the first line:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I've tried other operations, such as `folder.GetFilesAsync()` with the same error.  Is there another or capability that I need to allow this functionality to work correctly?

EDIT:

Based on @L.T.s answer, I tried some other capabilities.  The following gives me the same error:

```
var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;            
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

However (obviously, providing I provide the Music capability) this does not:

```
var testfolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
var files = await testfolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

I don't doubt that this it something specific to my Pictures library, but I have no idea what that could be.

Comment: You are sure that the exception is thrown from the first call? Is there a callstack? Also - can you show us what you pass in inside `path`?

Comment: Yes - it's the first call.  Path is set to `test.png`, but as I've said, if I call GetFilesAsync I get the same behaviour

Comment: Can you share a repro project?

Comment: Regarding a reproduction project; I literally just created a brand new store app blank project, added Pictures capabilities and put a button on the main form that calls the above code

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759031/hresult-e-fail-when-trying-to-create-a-folder-thats-name-contains-a-colon-in-wi) is related?

Comment: I had come across that, but since I simply want to read the directory, I didn't see how there could have been an issue with the filename.

Answer (score 2):

If your cost is just to preview an image. You can use this

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/test.png");
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = bitmap;
```

and add the image to a canvas. But you need to add your test.png to your projects assets first or you can change the Uri to the location of your test image.

Comment: Yes - I can get it working if i add the image to the project, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.  I want to preview an image from somewhere on the machine (for example, in the Pictures folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Image Name="img"></Image>
        <Button Name="btn" Click="Btn_OnClick"></Button>

    </Grid>


private async void Btn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var file = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("images.jpg");
            var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(fileStream);
            img.Source = image;

        }
```

I have windows8.1 and with vs.2013. Don't see any error. Could be something else?

Comment: I've updated my post.  I'm sure it is something else (that is, the 5 lines of code themselves are fine).  My question is: what?  I've tried reading different image types and, as my edit above illustrates, I've tried different interactions.  It does seem to be specific to the Pictures library.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //////to load an image file just do this
//put this in your app.xaml
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var root = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var mainPage = root.Content as MainPage;
        if (mainPage != null && args is FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs)
        {
            mainPage.ContinueFileOpenPicker(args as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs);
        }
    }

//and this in your btn event


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker
    {
        ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    };
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
}

//and this in you page

public void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs fileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs)
{
    if (fileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs.Files != null)
    {
        // Do something with selected file/s
    }
}
```